# Randomly filling with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Good day!
Can imagemagick do something like this:
create image size 2000-3000 and fill this image with images from source folder without needing to use coordinates?

Comment: Your question is vague. Why would filling from an image in a folder need coordinates? How do you want the new image filled?  Do you want to tile it out with the smaller image from the source folder?  Do yo want to do something else. Please show an example or explain further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick 7, you can make a random collage of images from a directory using the ashlar: syntax as follows:

```
cd desktop/testing
magick *.jpg -define ashlar:best-fit=true ashlar:result.jpg[2000x2000+0+0]
```

[image]

See ashlar: under pseudo-images at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo