# Is that possible to put different size images into a fixed width canvas with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have many different size images, I'm wondering is that possible to put them into a fixed width canvas without scale the images to generate a new big image? The canvas height need to be auto increased depend on the images' size and amount. How could I do it with ImageMagick?

[image: Example]

Comment: I think you want Fred's answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68103898/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Looks cool, but I need to put mergin for each image not stick together. And also the height for the canvas needs to be auto increased. Thank you.

Comment: I'm no expert on ashlar, so you may need to wait an hour or 2 for Fred to come online. You could maybe try adding `-geometry +10+10` near the start of the command to see if it respects that as spacing/margin. You could also maybe try changing the geometry in the square brackets at the end to `[2000x]` to see if will just accept a width and do the height automagically. Also try `[2000x+10+10]` to see if it accepts spacing/margin that way.

Comment: The geometry specification in square brackets is interpreted as `[width x height + xOffset + yOffset]`

Comment: Well done! Feel free to write up, and accept your own answer so future readers know what worked for you - then we can all learn.

Comment: Ashlar is the closest Imagemagick has to do that automatically. But it rearranges the image to best fit the space. If you want to do that mostly automatically, you can use +append to build the rows and then -append to append all the rows together. In you case above, leave off the bottom left image. Once you have all the rows appended and have a space there, you can composite the last image into that space. Alternately, you can create a command using -page +X+Y for each image to place into the correct location and then use -mosaic to combine the images. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/

Comment: I did something a bit similar years ago that you could maybe adapt if you wanted to invest some more effort... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625536/2836621

Comment: P.S. If you want to use +append to build the rows and -append to combine the rows and you want space between the images, you can use +smush and -smush in place of the appends. The smush command has and argument that is the space between the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use +append to build the rows and then -append to append all the rows together. In you case above, leave off the bottom left image. Once you have all the rows appended and have a space there, you can composite the last image into that space. Alternately, you can create a command using -page +X+Y for each image to place into the correct location and then use -mosaic to combine the images. See imagemagick.org/Usage/layers

P.S. If you want to use +append to build the rows and -append to combine the rows and you want space between the images, you can use +smush and -smush in place of the appends. The smush command has and argument that is the space between the images.